# How to make a button shows up under certain condition?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am student learning JavaScript.

For my private project, I am trying to create a survey that links to Google review page if clients chose good or very good. If client chose average or below, it goes to next step where people can fill out a form.

However, I am having trouble on the button function. I tried to "Next" button and depends on the clients' answer, the button do one the the above with if and else.

```js
function buttonConditions() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("question_1");
  var y = document.getElementsByName("process");
  var z = document.getElementsByName("forward");
  if (x === "good_1"
    or "very_good_1") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    z.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="main_question">How was the service provided?</h3>

<div class="review_block_smiles">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very bad" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_1" for="very_bad_1"><span>Very bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Bad" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_2" for="bad_1"><span>Bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="average_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Average" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_3" for="average_1"><span>Average</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Good" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_4" for="good_1"><span>Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very Good" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_5" for="very_good_1"><span>Very Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="submit" name="process" class="submit" style="display:none"><a href="www.google.com">Submit</a></button>

  <button> type="button " name="forward " class="forward " style="display:none ">Next</button>
```

I am okay with php part and others, but it is just those buttons don't work out as I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function getRadioGroupValue(radioGroupName) {
    let selectedOption = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(radioGroupName))
    .find((option) => option.checked);
  
  if (selectedOption) {
    return selectedOption.value;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

function buttonConditions() {
  var x = getRadioGroupValue("question_1");
  var y = document.getElementsByName("process")[0];
  var z = document.getElementsByName("forward")[0];
  
  if (x === "good_1" || x === "very_good_1") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    z.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="main_question">How was the service provided?</h3>

<div class="review_block_smiles">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very bad" onchange="buttonConditions();">
        <label class="radio smile_1" for="very_bad_1"><span>Very bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Bad" onchange="buttonConditions();">
        <label class="radio smile_2" for="bad_1"><span>Bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="average_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Average" onchange="buttonConditions();">
        <label class="radio smile_3" for="average_1"><span>Average</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="good_1" onchange="buttonConditions();">
        <label class="radio smile_4" for="good_1"><span>Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="very_good_1" onchange="buttonConditions();">
        <label class="radio smile_5" for="very_good_1"><span>Very Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="submit" name="process" class="submit" style="display:none"><a href="www.google.com">Submit</a></button>

  <button type="button " name="forward" class="forward " style="display:none ">Next</button>
  </div>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyhjew6s/21/)

---

**Explanations**

This condition:

```
if (x === "good_1"
  or "very_good_1") {
    y.style.display = "block";
} else {
    z.style.display = "block";
}
```

which produces this error in the console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after condition
```

does not follow Javascript's syntax: the `or` operator is done with symbol `||` (see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR) for more information). Also, you can't write

```
if (x == y || z)
```

to check if `x` is equal to `y` or to `z`. Instead, you should write

```
if (x == y || x == z)
```

---

[document.getElementsByName("...")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName) does not return a single element, but instead it returns a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). So to get your elements `y` and `z`, you should take the first element of that array:

```
var y = document.getElementsByName("process")[0];
var z = document.getElementsByName("forward")[0];
```

(note the trailing `[0]`).

Also note that `question_1` is a radio group. To get the value of a radio group (in vanilla Javascript) you cannot simply do

```
let x = document.getElementsByName("myRadioGroup");
console.log(x.value);
```

instead you should check every single element of the NodeList and get the value of the `checked` element (if any). You can use this function:

```
function getRadioGroupValue(radioGroupName) {
    let selectedOption = Array.from(document.getElementsByName(radioGroupName))
    .find((option) => option.checked);
  
  if (selectedOption) {
    return selectedOption.value;
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}

let x = getRadioGroupValue("question_1");
```

---

You have also some errors in your HTML code too. The  tag is not correctly closed and you have a missing  tag.

Also you are invoking a function which has not been defined in our `onchange="..."` event.

---

**EDIT**

To navigate user to the next step, you should replace your `<button name="forward">` with an [anchor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) (e.g. a link to the next page):

```
<a href="next-step.html" name="forward" class="forward " style="display:none ">Next</a>
```

See [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyhjew6s/22/) for the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The code you attached had the button tag opened, does this fix it?

```js
function buttonConditions() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("question_1");
  var y = document.getElementsByName("process");
  var z = document.getElementsByName("forward");
  if (x === "good_1"
    or "very_good_1") {
    y.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    z.style.display = "block";
  }
}
```

```html
<h3 class="main_question">How was the service provided?</h3>

<div class="review_block_smiles">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very bad" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_1" for="very_bad_1"><span>Very bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Bad" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_2" for="bad_1"><span>Bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="average_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Average" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_3" for="average_1"><span>Average</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Good" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_4" for="good_1"><span>Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very Good" onchange="getVals(this, 'question_1');">
        <label class="radio smile_5" for="very_good_1"><span>Very Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="submit" name="process" class="submit" style="display:none"><a href="www.google.com">Submit</a></button>

  <button type="button " name="forward" class="forward" style="display:none">Next</button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, the button does not show up at all. I thought it was related to script part, but I cannot figure out how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
<script>
  function setVisibility(elem) {
    var next = document.getElementById("next-button");
    var submit = document.getElementById("submit-button");

    if (elem.id === "good_1" || elem.id === "very_good_1") {
      next.setAttribute("style", "");
      submit.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
    } else {
      next.setAttribute("style", "display:none");
      submit.setAttribute("style", "");
    }
  }
</script>

<h3 class="main_question">How was the service provided?</h3>

<div class="review_block_smiles">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="very_bad_1"
          name="question_1"
          class="required"
          value="Very bad"
          onchange="setVisibility(this);"
        />
        <label class="radio smile_1" for="very_bad_1"
          ><span>Very bad</span></label
        >
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="bad_1"
          name="question_1"
          class="required"
          value="Bad"
          onchange="setVisibility(this);"
        />
        <label class="radio smile_2" for="bad_1"><span>Bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="average_1"
          name="question_1"
          class="required"
          value="Average"
          onchange="setVisibility(this);"
        />
        <label class="radio smile_3" for="average_1"
          ><span>Average</span></label
        >
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="good_1"
          name="question_1"
          class="required"
          value="Good"
          onchange="setVisibility(this);"
        />
        <label class="radio smile_4" for="good_1"><span>Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input
          type="radio"
          id="very_good_1"
          name="question_1"
          class="required"
          value="Very Good"
          onchange="setVisibility(this);"
        />
        <label class="radio smile_5" for="very_good_1"
          ><span>Very Good</span></label
        >
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button type="submit" id="submit-button" class="hode" style="display:none ">
    Submit
  </button>

  <button id="next-button" type="button " name="forward " style="display:none ">
    Next
  </button>
</div>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vm1c7z?file=index.html

Comment: YES!!!!! Thank you so much!!!!!! This was what I tried to do!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is also working solution. You can use JS `filter` to search for the checked element inside the array. In this case it is the radio button, so we can use `[0]` index. Having the point we can get its value by adding `.value` at the end.

Also, it is very helpful to listen on the change event. You can do this using for example `addEventListener`.

```js
function buttonConditions() {
  var x = document.getElementsByName("question_1");
  var y = document.getElementById("process");
  var z = document.getElementById("forward");
  
  let valueChecked = [...x].filter(v => v.checked)[0].value
  if (valueChecked === "Good" || valueChecked === "Very Good")   {
      y.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      z.style.display = "block";
    }

}

(function () {

    var x = document.getElementsByName("question_1");
    x.forEach(e => {
        e.addEventListener("change", buttonConditions)
    })

})()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app">

        <h3 class="main_question">How was the service provided?</h3>

<div class="review_block_smiles">
  <ul class="clearfix">
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very bad">
        <label class="radio smile_1" for="very_bad_1"><span>Very bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="bad_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Bad">
        <label class="radio smile_2" for="bad_1"><span>Bad</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="average_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Average">
        <label class="radio smile_3" for="average_1"><span>Average</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Good">
        <label class="radio smile_4" for="good_1"><span>Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="container_smile">
        <input type="radio" id="very_good_1" name="question_1" class="required" value="Very Good">
        <label class="radio smile_5" for="very_good_1"><span>Very Good</span></label>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <button id="process" type="submit" name="process" class="submit" style="display:none"><a href="https://google.com">Submit</a></button>
  <button id="forward" type="button " name="forward " class="forward" style="display:none">Next</button>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```